# S3 transfer manager intialization extremely slow in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm running downloads against keys with ~300-500 objects (small). Total size ~300mb. This is running on an Ec2 instance as well, so network is over the AWS backbone.

```
    System.out.println("Initializing downloader");
    MultipleFileDownload downloader =
        transferManager.downloadDirectory(bucket, keyPrefix, new File(dest));
    System.out.println("Downloader metadata initialized successfully");

    long percentage = 0;
    while (!downloader.isDone()) {
      percentage++;
      if (percentage % 500 == 0)
        System.out.println(downloader.getProgress().getPercentTransferred() + "% complete");
    }
    System.out.println("Completion Status: " + downloader.isDone());
```

This line right here:

```
    MultipleFileDownload downloader =
        transferManager.downloadDirectory(bucket, keyPrefix, new File(dest));
```

takes roughly 5 minutes to run, before it even hits my for loop to start downloading. I did run this locally to visualize the profiling and I see that most of the time, the threads are just waiting until Net I/O kicks in. Why is this? I can see 10 concurrent threads when profiling.

Comment: Not necessarily the cause for the delay, but unless you are running an S3 endpoint, it's still going out to the Internet to access the public S3 API, so not completely within the AWS network.

Comment: If you enable [the wire logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html), you'll be able to see exactly where it's spending the time.